# Magento 2 - How to disable cronjob temporarily

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have a crojob in my custom module and want to disable it temporarily

The xml files for the cronjob are:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/cron_groups.xml
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/crontab.xml
```

I have tried to comment out the code from cron scheduling

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="my_cron_id">

        <!--<job name="my_cron_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\MyCron" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 3 * * *</schedule>
        </job>-->

    </group>
</config>
```

But after this, my module went stopped working with no error.

I just simply wants to disable it temporarily how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you have only one cronjob in your crontab.xml file and you want to remove it, you should rename your file to be _crontab.xml and clear the cache.

Comment: I renamed both xml files with `_`. I hope I would find proper solution for this, but for now it resolved the issue. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: i had the similar issue with events.xml file. I had only one event and i tried to comment that, which causes magento to showing me error as when magento is reading xml, it expects atleast one element or else it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the cron command **`cron:remove`**.
[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cron-remove)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it will remove all the cronjobs of magento, not just my custom cronjob

Answer (score 0):

You could try `php bin/magento cron:remove`. Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-group-run for more details